# Hover state seems to be sticky

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

The hover state on links seems to be unpleasantly sticky in Opera.  The mouse out handler doesn't seem to be always called.

I'm running Opera 12.16 on Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Reproduced (also Opera 12.16 / Linux). The highlighting is just done using a standard CSS `:hover` selector, so it seems to be a bug in Opera. Strangely, opening the developer console seems to stop the bug from happening, which makes it kind of tricky to test.